# how to understand the * argument here?

Tags: python

Hi i have several lines of python code, which confuses me:

```
def apply_async(func, args,*, callback):
    # Compute the result
    result = func(*args)
    # Invoke the callback with the result
    callback(result)

def print_result(result):
    print('Got:', result)

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

apply_async(add, (2, 3), callback=print_result)
```

I understand that to write a function that accepts any number of positional arguments, use a * argument.

But i couldn't understand why `*` appear ater `args`.
and then `*args` can represent the tuple `(2,3)` in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102. All arguments after the `*` must be named arguments.